# Access to an inner struct/class in C#

Tags: c#, class-design

I have a class that has an inner struct/class (I have decided which yet, if it matters for this I will use that) I want the inner class to be accessed from other classes but only constructed by the outer class. 
Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you can get is an `internal` constructor, unfortunately. While `private` and `protected` members of an outer class are available to an inner class, the opposite is not true.

Comment: internal seems to work, I would have liked to have only the outer class have access but this is good enough. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Why not declaring an inner interface (or an inner abstract class) so that's not instantiatable, then a private inner class that implements the interface ?

Something like

```
using System;
namespace test {

    class Outer {

        public interface IInner {
            void SayHello();
        }

        private class Inner : IInner {
            public void SayHello() {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            }
        }

        public IInner MakeInner() {
            return new Inner();
        }

    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Outer x = new Outer();
            x.MakeInner().SayHello();
        }
    }
}
```

In this way only `Outer` can create concrete `Inner` objects, while other classes must invoke the `MakeInner` method.
Please note that in this way you are also enforcing the constraint for classes in the same assembly.